# im stuck with onerror / php | Get a space in output

Tags: javascript, php

Have this as a part in a ajax search page

index.php

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#user').keyup(function(){  
            var query = $(this).val();  
            if(query != '')  
            {  
                $.ajax({  
                    url:"search.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{query:query},  
                    success:function(data)  
                    {  
                        $('#postList').fadeIn();  
                        $('#postList').html(data);  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        });  
  
    });
```

search.php

```
$output .= '<div class="bild"><img src="'.$row["URL"].'" width="200" height="300" alt="'.$row["Titel"].'" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="loading.jpg";"/></div>';
$output .= '</div>';
```

The problem is that i get a space in index.php when i activate it

```
this.src=" loading.jpg"
```

Anyone have any good explanation for why this is and also im happy if someone can get me in right path :)

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vknNo.jpg)

Need to get away the space ..

```
this.src="loading.jpg"
```

Comment: Anything outside of `<?php` and the optional `?>` is passed as-is to output. I'd wager that one of your PHP files starts with ` <?php`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have double quotes inside double quotes, change one of the to single quotes or escape the ones inside:

```
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="loading.jpg";"
```

Try to do this:

```
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="\loading.jpg\";"
```

or this:

```
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='loading.jpg';"
```

or this:

```
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'loading.jpg\';"
```

One of them should fix it, just try with your code which one is best.

Comment: You made a old enthusiast happy :)
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'loading.jpg\';" 
made the trick

3 first one gave same result, space as before

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You quotations marks for loading.jpg are not escaped, thereby it is treating the loading.jpg as an attribute of the div tag and not as a src parameter of this. Replace the quotes around loading.jpg with `\'` and it should work.

I quickly typed the example in an interactive PHP shell to show you the effect.

First what your result was (you see that loading.jpg is in a different color highlighted):

```
php > $output = '<div class="bild"><img src="'.$row["URL"].'" width="200" height="300" alt="'.$row["Titel"].'" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="loading.jpg";"/></div>';
php > echo($output);
<div class="bild"><img src="http:\demo.com" width="200" height="300" alt="Demo" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="loading.jpg";"/></div>
```

And now my fix:

```
php > $output = '<div class="bild"><img src="'.$row["URL"].'" width="200" height="300" alt="'.$row["Titel"].'" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'loading.jpg\';"/></
div>';
php > echo($output);
<div class="bild"><img src="http:\demo.com" width="200" height="300" alt="Demo" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='loading.jpg';"/></div>
```